# Learning Python else syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, if-statement, python-2.7

Hi I am learning python by doing the practice problems for Open course at [MIT 6.00 Intro to Computer Science](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/assignments/pset3.pdf).

I am Trying to do practice problem 1 part 2 create a recursive function to count the instance of key in target. My code so far...

```
from string import *
def countSubStringMatchRecursive (target, key,x,s):
   if (find(target,key)==find(target,key,s)) and (find(target,key)==find(target,key,(find(target,key)))):#if first and last
      return (1)
   elif (find(target,key)==find(target,key,s))and (find(target,key)!=find(target,key,(find(target,key)))):#if first but not last
      x=1
      s= find(target,key)
      return (countSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key,s,x)
   elif (find(target,key,s))==-1 and (find(target,key)!=find(target,key,s)):#if last but not first
      return (x+1)
   elif:(find(target,key,s))!=-1 and (find(target,key)!=find(target,key,s)):#if not last and not first
      x=x+1
      s= find(target,key,s)
      return (countSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key,s,x)
```

I getting a syntax error at line 8. I would just like to know what I did wrong there. Dont worry about the other mistakes I should be able to get those sorted out. I just Stuck on this. Thanks.

Comment: your last `elif` has one colon before the expression. Might also be a problem.

Comment: Others will find it easier to read your Python code if you follow the guidelines in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You will find it easier to read too!!!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in line 8 and in the last line. Actually, the corresponding opening parenthesis is unnecessary, you might as well rewrite those line as this:

```
return countSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key,s,x)
```

Also, as pointed by @rodion in the comments, the last `elif` has a misplaced `:`, remove the one right before the opening parenthesis.

And talking about parenthesis: in Python you don't have to place the conditions of an `if ... elif ... else` statement inside parenthesis, you should drop them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment It was very helpful. I have since fixed the problems and more I found and its working fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an unmatched paren on line 8. Add another close paren at the end

`return (countSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key,s,x))`

Same thing applies to your final return statement.

Comment: Thank you for your comment It was very helpful. I have since fixed the problems and more I found and its working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatched parenthesis. Remove the `(` near the beginning of the line or add a `)` to the end.

Comment: Thank you for your comment It was very helpful. I have since fixed the problems and more I found and its working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

1. You are missing a closing paren on line 8
2. the body of your function needs to be indented. (*update*: has been fixed)
3. Also, your last `elif` has a `:` right after it, that needs to be
   deleted. I.e.,

   ```
   elif: expression:
   ```

   should be

   ```
   elif expression:
   ```
4. Your last statement is also missing a closing paren

   ```
   return (countSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key,s,x)
   ```

   should be

   ```
   return (countSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key,s,x))
   ```

Finally @drewk's recommendation about taking a look at the [**PEP 8**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is a good one. I periodically go back and review it myself.

Also, you have a number of unnecessary `()`s .. they don't do any harm, but they are not needed and may reduce the readability of your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment It was very helpful. I have since fixed the problems and more I found and its working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
return (countSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key,s,x)
```

You're missing a closing `)`. But you didn't need the opening one either; the syntax of a `return` statement is `return <expr>`, so anything that's a valid expression can directly follow `return`. Anything that's a valid expression is still a valid expression meaning exactly the same thing if you surround it with parentheses, but mostly that just adds noise when it's not needed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment It was very helpful. I have since fixed the problems and more I found and its working fine. :)